# OneSignal don't build in Phonegap-build anymore

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, onesignal

Since yesterday I cannot build a Phonegap-build app that includ OneSignal plugin, it dose not work anymore! I am using the version 2.4.5 
here is the error I get:
Any idea ?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/app/build.gradle' line: 94
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.10.0, 0.99.99].
  >    Required by:
  >        unspecified:unspecified:unspecified
  >   Could not resolve gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.10.0, 0.99.99].
  >   Failed to list versions for gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin.
  >   Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/gradle/plugin/com/onesignal/onesignal-gradle-plugin/maven-metadata.xml.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/gradle/plugin/com/onesignal/onesignal-gradle-plugin/maven-metadata.xml'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/gradle/plugin/com/onesignal/onesignal-gradle-plugin/maven-metadata.xml'.
  >   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

It worked the day before with the same OneSignal plugin version, and I did not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there has been an issue with the gradle SSL certificate and they fixed it!  now it should be working fine, try to build with your previously working version 2.4.5 and let me know what you got.

Answer (score 1):

I solved changing onesignal plugin version:

Before I was using (with problem):

Works only with version 2.4.0:

You need to put exactly spec="2.4.0" not spec="^2.4.0".

Comment: You'r absolutely right, it works. But what is strange is that it works fine with version 2.4.5, and suddenly from just yesterday it doesn't work anymore..!!

Comment: It's a OneSignal back end issue, they should fix it, anything that's updated on Android side can affect their plugin, but they definitely have to be up to date.